# Refactoring 3 small bits of PHP function into JS - array, if empty and matching url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm not much of a JS person but I'd like to know how to run my PHP into JS. How can I do the following using Javascript only?

```
// 1. Getting the request
<?php if($_GET["slider"]=="1"){ ?>
$(".class1 a").click()      
<?php } ?>
<?php if($_GET["slider"]=="2"){ ?>
$(".class2 a").click()

// 2. Matching the URL and setting an active class on the list item
<li><a href="my_page.php" class="<?php if (strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'my_page') !== FALSE ) {?>active<?php } ?>">My Page</a></li>

// 3. Nav array and If empty
<?php
$navigation = array(
    'previous'  => 'page1.php',
);

if (isset($navigation['previous']))
{
?>
<div class="prev">
    <a href="<?php echo $navigation['previous']; ?>">
        <span class="previous-icon"></span><span>Previous</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

My attempt after Googling..

```
<?php if(var _GET["slider"]=="1"){ } if(_GET["slider"]=="2"){ if (strrpos(var _SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'my_page') !== false ) {} var navigation = {
    'previous'  : 'page1.php',
};

if ((navigation['previous']))
{
```

Comment: Dont mix php with js. Use ajax.

Comment: @aliasm2k Thanks for the heads up. I want to completely remove PHP from this application and turn it into static HTML with JS.

Comment: Then use ajax to interact with external php file. A quick google will help

Comment: The server I need to throw the files on doesn't support PHP whatsoever. So I'm looking for a JS based solution for the above function.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I have JQuery included on the page so yep that's no problem to use JQuery for this "refactor". Using it for a slider gallery

Answer (score 0):

1. you can get "GET" values (query string) like in this **[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/808393)**
2. `window.location.href.indexOf("my_page") != -1` , search for window.location and indexOf for further explanation
3. check code

   ```
   var navigation = {previous:"page1.php"};
   document.write('<a href="'+navigation["previous"]+'">....');`
   ```

Arrays can't have string indexes in js, you need to use objects;
you can also use navigation.previous instead.

you can't mix js and html like you do with php, you have to "echo" everything using **document.write** or other **DOM manipulation** functions. For further help on these topics, search the bold parts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Quad - great to see someone happy to assist and get me to understand more about it. I'll give this a crack and accept the answer once I've resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your three questions:

1: Clicking something if a variable is in the URL (i.e. `/page.php?slider=1`): Check out [this page](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html), which details how to retrieve variables from URLs in jQuery. In short, you can do something like,

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

to get the variables from a URL, and from there you can check if a variable is set by asking `getUrlvars()['slider'] == 1`.

2: Matching the url and setting a class as active: You can do something like

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://www.example.com/page.php') {
   $('a').addClass('active');
}
```

3: If you're looking to create a dynamic list of links using Javascript arrays, you could do something like this:

```
var myLinks = {
  "link_1_title": "http://www.example.com", 
  "link_2_title": "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
}
$.each(myLinks, function(key, val) {
    $('.navbar').append('<a href="' + val + '">' + key + '</a>');
}
```

For a more detailed explanation about `jQuery.each`, please see [the jQuery doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got an unholy alliance here of PHP drawing the JS and then the JS doing things. It's a recipe for disaster. Your PHP should pass your data to your JS and then let the JS do the work. Don't mix logic. Have a clean handoff.

```
<script>
var something = <?php echo $var ?>;
myclass = new someClass(something);
</script>
```